# Delphi 2005, can't build Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm receiving an error when building the `IdMessageHelper.pas` unit in the `IndyProtocols90` package.  All instances of `LoadFromStream` and `LoadFromFile` are claiming there is an issue with the signature:

> [Error] IdMessageHelper.pas(78): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'LoadFromStream' that can be called with these arguments

```
procedure Internal_TIdMessageHelper_LoadFromStream(AMsg: TIdMessage; AStream: TStream;
  const AHeadersOnly: Boolean; const AUsesDotTransparency: Boolean);
var
  LMsgClient: TIdMessageClient;
begin
  if AUsesDotTransparency then begin
    AMsg.LoadFromStream(AStream, AHeadersOnly);
  end else
  begin
    // clear message properties, headers before loading
    AMsg.Clear;
    LMsgClient := TIdMessageClient.Create;
    try
      Internal_TIdMessageClientHelper_ProcessMessage(LMsgClient, AMsg, AStream, AHeadersOnly, False);
    finally
      LMsgClient.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I see that `IdMessageHelper` is new to this version, but the method that's being called (`IdMessage.LoadFromStream` for example), the arguments for it haven't changed from the last few versions - at least not for the ones that I have the source.

```
procedure TIdMessage.LoadFromStream(AStream: TStream; const AHeadersOnly: Boolean = False);
var
  LMsgClient: TIdMessageClient;
begin
  // clear message properties, headers before loading
  Clear;
  LMsgClient := TIdMessageClient.Create;
  try
    LMsgClient.ProcessMessage(Self, AStream, AHeadersOnly);
  finally
    LMsgClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm pretty sure I removed all previous versions and packages since this was a clean install of D2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IdMessageHelper` unit introduces new `LoadFrom...()` and `SaveTo...()` methods for the `TIdMessage` component, to add an `AUsesDotTransparency` parameter when loading/saving emails.

In Delphi 2005 and later, it does this by defining a [class helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_helper) (which is a feature introduced in Delphi 2005) to add new methods to the `TIdMessage` component without having to modify the `IdMessage.pas` unit itself.  This allows Indy to let people use familiar `IdMessage1.LoadFrom...()` and `IdMessage1.SaveTo...()` syntax when using the new functionality <sup>1</sup>.

Things were done this way so as not to cause interface breaking changes in the `IdMessage` unit itself.  I blogged about this new addition at the time the `IdMessageHelper.pas` unit was first added to Indy:

[New TIdMessage helper](http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20150730.aspx)

In your case, the error message is complaining about Line 78:

```
AMsg.LoadFromStream(AStream, AHeadersOnly);
```

That line is the new 3-parameter `TIdMessageHelper.LoadFromStream()` method attempting to call the pre-existing 2-parameter `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` method when `AUsesDotTransparency` is True:

```
procedure TIdMessage.LoadFromStream(AStream: TStream; const AHeadersOnly: Boolean = False);
```

I have tested this new class helper in later Delphi versions and it works fine for me.  You should not be getting a compiler error, as there should not be any ambiguity.

However, I have not tested the class helper in Delphi 2005 specifically (as I do not have that version installed), so it is possible that the compiler error could be indicating that class helpers (being a new language feature at the time) were still a little buggy, and were fixed later on.

If you can't find the cause of the ambiguity, you can work around the issue by modifying `IdMessageHelper.pas` to undefine `HAS_CLASS_HELPER` for Delphi 2005 <sup>1</sup>, and then recompile Indy again.

<sup>1</sup>: In older versions of Delphi where class helpers are not available, `IdMessageHelper.pas` also defines several standalone `TIdMessageHelper_LoadFrom...()` and `TIdMessageHelper_SaveTo...()` functions, so people can still utilize the new `AUsesDotTransparency` functionality, just with a less-desirable calling syntax.

---

**EDIT**: it turns out that class helpers were very buggy in Delphi 2005, and [were not officially supported until Delphi 2006](http://www.marcocantu.com/md2005/UpdateDelphi2006_ch04.html):

> Class helpers have now been formally introduced in the Win32 compiler [in Delphi 2006]. In Delphi 2005 **class helpers were not formally available, and although you could use them they were actually quite buggy**. It was quite easy to get internal compiler errors while using them, nothing you could complain to with Borland about as **this feature was not officially supported**.

So, I have now disabled the `TIdMessageHelper` helper class in Delphi 2005, and have updated the above mentioned blog article accordingly.

Comment: The problem exists within `IdMessageHelper.pas` and `IdIMAP4.pas`.  I simply changed the check to `{$IFDEF VCL_2006_OR_ABOVE}` and it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Class helpers were introduced in D2005, so I would still like to understand why the code is not working in D2005 (especially since the failure only occurs on line 78, right? Line 50 is another overloaded call into a `TIdMessage` method, but it doesn't fail, right?).

Comment: If you rename the helper methods in `IdMessageHelper.pas` (say, to `LoadFrom...Ex()` and `SaveTo...Ex()`), but still call the original `TIdMessage` methods on lines 50 and 78, does the problem go away in D2005?

Comment: Nevermind. I have now disabled the class helper in D2005.